# Ethereum Production Infrastructure

Tags: ether, private-blockchain, blockchain-as-a-service

Could someone recommend which environment (i.e Microsoft or Ubuntu) is a better choice for prototyping proof of concept idea for blockchain using Ethereum together with a short description what they are good for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux implementation of geth is known to be more stable (related to keeping network connection open, which is an issue in windows).

Ubuntu seems to work well (but not available in 'promise' distrib)

Also, linux is more appropriate for console based work (manipulating the node via the geth console, manipulating log files ...).

Personally, I was rusty on my linux skills but manipulating ethereum via linux forces to better understand all the technical dimensions of geth (ipc, listening ports, memory usage, ...)

Good luck and ask for help if needed.